# Sublime Text system cannot find file

Tags: c++, mingw, sublimetext

ive been trying to run c++ codes on sublime for a while but im having this problem "The system cannot find the file specified."
i tried googling for solutions but couldnt find any answer:

[image: 1]

Comment: I am not sure but try moving the code from `C:\` to any other directory.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: `g++` is in your environment variables and can you invoke it in the command line?

Comment: your input file is named `input.txt.txt`. Since you're just trying to get a program to compile and run, edit your `.sublime-build` file and remove `< input.txt` from the end of the `shell_cmd`.

Comment: @HamzaAnis yes i can

Comment: @MattDMo now im having this error  /mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file D:\Programs\code.exe: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

As you only specify `input.txt` without full path it's looking for it in the current folder the program is run: `C:\Users\AboodPC\Desktop\Programs`.
So either make sure `C:\Users\AboodPC\Desktop\Programs\input.txt` exists, or specify the full path in `shell_cmd` after the `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an **input.txt** file to take input into the program at run time.

Answer (score 0):

In sublime text 3

Simply  name your input file as "inputf.in"
And output file as "outputf.in"

And create new build system
Tool-->bulid system  -->new build system

And paste below code

{"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++14", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],"selector":"source.cpp","shell":true,"working_dir":"$file_path"}

And save as name as"c++14.sublime-build"

And run the program  ctrl+shift+B